# mod-rewrite not changing the input url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

mod-rewrite question.

Why the following code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/forms/index.php?i=$1 [QSA,L]
```

results in the url changing from

http://www.example.com/search/foo/bar

to

http://www.example.com/forms/index.php?i=foo/bar

while the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /forms/index.php [L]
```

does not change the input url?

Any insight?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you have `http://www.example.com`, mod_rewrite **implicity** redirects, it's the same as putting `R` in the rule's flags.

In the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), under "Substitution strings" it says:

> **Absolute URL**
>
> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL. To force an external redirect back to the current host, see the [R] flag below.